# Do any of Apple's devices support iOS 4.0 but not multitasking?

Tags: ios, multitasking

Do any of Apple's devices support iOS 4.0 but not multitasking?

If not, I don't understand the `[UIDevice isMultitaskingSupported]` API (which was only introduced in iOS 4.0).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

- Iphone 3G
- Ipod Touch 2

Due to hardware limitations, they can run iOS4 but not actually make use of things like multitasking. On my old iPod touch, running iOS4 added a significant delay to the device's operation, even without multitasking.

Answer (score 3):

iPhone 3G doesn't support multitasking

Answer (score 1):

iPod touch 2g and iPhone 3g don't support native mustitasking. Multitasking can be disactivated on jailbroken devices, this is aswell recognizable using `isMultitaskingSupported`.